# Import code issues google

Tags: android, eclipse, import, google-api, google-places-api

I have been working with Java for about a couple of months now and I have been stuck introducing Google API into my Maps app. I need some help with these imports.

Here is what I did: I was following the code of a Places API demo which I can link if needed. I ended up having to add some libraries. Before I did, I was getting errors from all of the imports that started with com.google.api.client...etc. Then once I added all of these libraries, I then got left with 2 errors out of my imports.

The errors are: the "com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders" and "com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser". I am receiving them both as "cannot be resolved to a type". These errors are causing some more errors throughout the rest of my code. I was hoping someone can help me solve this. I know it should have something to do with my code, but I am not sure what is going on. I know I am missing something.

Also, I installed the Google Plugin to install the APIs and when I did, I added the "Google + API" and the "GoogleOAuth2" APIs and that is where I am stuck at. Please someone help.

Here is the screenshot:  [Full Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/a/img191/6830/5izh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Maps, but as I understand it Maps is now packaged with Google Play Services, which I have been working with recently.

Firstly, the installation of Google Play Services is well-documented and you should look at this (if you haven't done so already):

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

There are a few areas that cause difficulty, and one is the section "Set Up a Project with the Library". There are different possible approaches but I suggest you take the following steps.

Ensure that the Google Play Services lib (and any other libs) are defined as library projects (Properties ...Android.. Library ...IsLibrary) and that they have no errors (cleaning may not be sufficient - you may have to shut down Eclipse to remove the errors).

When the library projects are error free, add them to your project. The normal way of doing this is to REFERENCE them (check what the documentation says) but you do this by (Properties ...Android.. Library ...Add).

Then check out (Properties ... Java Build Path ...) - read the documentation but you need your libs in here.

Then clean your project but note that a restart of Eclipse may be necessary to remove the errors from your project.

There are other errors that can arise - another common one arises if you have different versions of the v4 support lib in your libs / project and you get a message "...this check is based on SHA1 at this time". This is well documented on Stack Overflow.

Good luck !

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer on this, I will try this as soon as I can. (I am currently at work) I do have a question though, this might be a stupid question and all (Im still a beginner in java), but could having as many libraries as I have currently create more errors? I say this because I have done my research about libraries and adapting them into apps, but I have only done a few and that was through tutorials. I have also already adapted Google Play services also, so that isn't a problem.